# How to auto-update SSH agent environment variables when attaching to existing tmux sessions?

Tags: tmux, ssh-agent

I am trying to find a nice way to restore the SSH agent when I reconnect a disconnected tmux session.

The cause seems to be that the SSH agent session changes but the environment variable from the tmux session is not updated.

How can I automate this, before attaching the session itself? Because the session I am attaching to does not always have a bash prompt, so I cannot afford to type something inside it. It has to be something to run before creating or attaching the tmux session.

An example of the code I'm running is at https://gist.github.com/ssbarnea/8646491 -- a small ssh wrapper that is using tmux to create persistem ssh connections. This works quite well, but sometimes the ssh agent stops working so I am no longer able to use it to connect to other hosts.

Comment: You probably should mark pymkin's response as the answer.

Answer (score 90):

There's an excellent [gist](https://gist.github.com/martijnvermaat/8070533) by Martijn Vermaat, which addresses your problem in great depth, although it is intended for screen users, so I'm adjusting it for tmux here.

To summarize:

1. create `~/.ssh/rc` if it doesn't exist yet, and add the following content:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash

   # Fix SSH auth socket location so agent forwarding works with tmux.
   if test "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ; then
     ln -sf $SSH_AUTH_SOCK ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
   fi
   ```
2. Make it work in tmux, add this to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

   ```bash
   # fix ssh agent when tmux is detached
   setenv -g SSH_AUTH_SOCK $HOME/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
   ```

Extra work is required if you want to enable X11 forwarding, see the [gist](https://gist.github.com/martijnvermaat/8070533).

Comment: When reconnecting to tmux, it doesn't update to the newest ssh_auth_sock... it stays with the one that originally created the session, so this doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: I had to add a `set -g update-environment -r` to the .tmux in order to get this process to work.  I also added some namespacing to the socket link creation: https://gist.github.com/bcomnes/e756624dc1d126ba2eb6

Comment: Fixed an error with the previous GIST: had change $(hostname) to $HOSTNAME in the .screenrc and .tmux.conf files

Comment: @bret - That gist works beatifully - How about creating a new answer with those 3 files?

Comment: @Pete There are still additional issue existing with the solution I posted outside the tmux session last I checked.  I'm currently experimenting with https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Keychain to solve this issue.

Comment: $HOSTNAME is rendering to empty string in my .tmux.conf. I am using FreeBSD. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't make the mistake I did, and add `-v` to the arguments to `ln` -- that causes the ssh connection to emit output, which I just discovered causes a remote Unison client to complain :-|

Comment: @Bret Your solution works fine if you detach from a tmux session, and then close SSH connection. However, it does not work if you close the ssh connection forcefully, still being attached to a tmux session (e.g. when you suddenly loose network connection and close SSH connection with [Shift ~][Enter]. Any ideas what could fix this?

Comment: @Bret Now that I investigated this a bit further, it seems to also fail when you detach from the session. To reproduce, run this in a tmux session: `sleep 5; ssh git@github.com` (making sure you have a github key in your SSH agent), and quickly detach while sleeping. Then re-attach and see how ssh says "Permission denied".

Comment: I think I ran into that issue eventually.  I never found a solution, but I didn't looked that hard.  I might revisit some day but if you find a solution, ping me!

Comment: @Bret Ping, any process?

Comment: No, I gave up sorry.

Comment: I've found how to make this work. Add the following to OP's answer in your ~/.tmux.conf: `set-option -g -u update-environment[3]`

Thing is, setting the tmux SSH_AUTH_SOCK in tmux's *global* environment isn't sufficient, because tmux by default picks up SSH_AUTH_SOCK from the *session* environment, and that overrides the global. But by adding `set-option -g -u update-environment[3]`  we're telling tmux *not* to pick up `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` on session attach, which lets our global setting apply.

`update-environment` is a tmux array variable, and index [3] is `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

Comment: Updated and elaborated in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70342647/481788) below

Answer (score 55):

While `tmux` [updates](http://man.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#update-environment__) `SSH` variables by default, there is no need to

- change/add socket path
- change the `SSH_AUTH_SOCKET` variable

I like the solution by [Chris Down](https://chrisdown.name/2013/08/02/fixing-stale-ssh-sockets-in-tmux.html) which I changed to add function

```shell
fixssh() {
    eval $(tmux show-env    \
        |sed -n 's/^\(SSH_[^=]*\)=\(.*\)/export \1="\2"/p')
}
```

into `~/.bashrc`. Call `fixssh` after attaching session or before `ssh`/`scp`/`rsync`.

Newer versions of `tmux` support `-s` option for `show-env`, so only

```
eval $(tmux show-env -s |grep '^SSH_')
```

is possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what worked for me! :) However, one small problem: when doing this in a reattached tmux pane, it doesn't work. I need to close the old pane, and open a new one. A fix for this is to detach tmux, show the `$DISPLAY` variable, reattach tmux, and set `$DISPLAY` correctly, in my case `export DISPLAY=localhost:14.0`, but the number seems to change at each ssh session.

Comment: "While tmux updates SSH variables by default" What are you talking about? (I suspect that the anchor in your link is now nonexistent.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky I fixed his link. You were right: anchor no longer existed. Looks to have a stable form now.

Comment: This should be the top answer. It is unnecessary to create a new temporary file.

Comment: While this solution is cleaner in that it doesn't require a temp file, it does depend on somehow executing the hook after reattaching (manually?) which conflicts with an explicit spec in the OP.

Answer (score 30):

Here's what I use for updating `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` inside a `tmux` window (based on Hans Ginzel's script):

```
alias fixssh='eval $(tmux showenv -s SSH_AUTH_SOCK)'
```

Or for `tmux` that does not have `showenv -s`:

```
alias fixssh='export $(tmux showenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK)'
```

Comment: I have added a test if SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set:
 alias fixssh='[[ "`tmux show-env SSH_AUTH_SOCK`" == "-SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]]
  && echo "Warning: No SSH_AUTH_SOCK set."
  || export $(tmux show-env SSH_AUTH_SOCK)'

Answer (score 8):

There are lots of good answers here. But there are cases where `tmux show-environment` doesn't see `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. In that case you can use `find` to locate it explicitly.

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(find /tmp -path '*/ssh-*' -name 'agent*' -uid $(id -u) 2>/dev/null | tail -n1)
```

That's long and complicated, so I'll break it down...

```
01  export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(
02    find /tmp \
03      -path '*/ssh-*'
04      -name 'agent*'
05      -uid $(id -u)
06      2>/dev/null
07    | tail -n1
08  )
```

1. `export` the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable set to the output of the `$()` command substitution
2. `find` files starting in `/tmp`
3. limit results to only those with `/ssh-` in the path
4. limit results to only those whose name begins with `agent`
5. limit results to only those with a user id matching the current user
6. silence all (permissions, etc.) errors
7. take only the last result if there are multiple

You may be able to leave off 6 & 7 if you know that there will only be 1 result and you don't care about stderr garbage.

Comment: Out of all solutions listed here, only this worked on mac.

Comment: Nice but it may be required to take only LAST ssh agent socket. To do that, we may add sorting into `find`: `find /tmp -path '*/ssh-*' -name 'agent*' -uid (id -u) -printf "%T+\t%p\n" 2>/dev/null | sort | tail -n1 | awk -F'\t' '{print $2 }'`

Comment: This was also the only solution that worked on a remote byobu session to which I connected from WSL in Windows with SSH_AUTH_SOCK coming from Keepass on Windows with a local socket from Keeagent!

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution which includes both approaches, and does not require extra typing when I reconnect to tmux session

```
alias ssh='[ -n "$TMUX" ] && eval $(tmux showenv -s SSH_AUTH_SOCK); /usr/bin/ssh'
```

Comment: It looks like it will execute `eval $(tmux showenv -s SSH_AUTH_SOCK)` in local, not remote!

Comment: I wrote this on the remote (tmux is running) and it worked as I expected. Thanks!

Comment: This will not work when ssh is called indirectly, e.g. `git fetch`.

Answer (score 4):

I use a variation of the previous answers:

```
eval "export $(tmux show-environment -g SSH_AUTH_SOCK)"
```

assuming that you did the ssh agent started from the outer environment. Same goes for other environment variables such as `DISPLAY`.

Comment: *Are you sure this works for you?* With `-g` I get the stale value of `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. Leaving away `-g` does the trick. See also other answers.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to avoid configuring TMUX (etc) and keep everything purely in `~/.ssh/`. On the **remote** system:

Create `~/.ssh/rc`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Fix SSH auth socket location so agent forwarding works within tmux
if test "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ; then
  ln -sf $SSH_AUTH_SOCK ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
fi
```

Add following to `~/.ssh/config` so it no longer relies on `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, which goes stale in detached terminals:

```
Host *
  IdentityAgent ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
```

#### Known limitations

- `ssh-add` doesn't use `~/.ssh/config` and so cannot communicate with `ssh-agent`. Commands like `ssh-add -l` produce errors, even though `ssh user@host` works fine, as does updating git remotes which are accessed via SSH.

Answer (score 2):

I may have worked out a solution that is fully encapsulated in the `~/.tmux.conf` configuration file.  It is a different approach than modifying the `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.ssh/rc`.

**Solution only using `~/.tmux.conf`**

Just cut and paste the following code into your `~/.tmux.conf`

```sh
# ~/.tmux.conf

# SSH agent forwarding
#
# Ensure that SSH-Agent forwarding will work when re-attaching to the tmux
#   session from a different SSH connection (after a dropped connection).
#   This code will run upon tmux create, tmux attach, or config reload.
#
# If there is an SSH_AUTH_SOCK originally defined:
#   1) Remove all SSH related env var names from update-environment.
#      Without this, setenv cannot override variables such as SSH_AUTH_SOCK.
#      Verify update-environment with: tmux show-option -g update-environment
#   2) Force-set SSH_AUTH_SOCK to be a known location
#      /tmp/ssh_auth_sock_tmux
#   3) Force-create a link of the first found ssh-agent socket at the known location
if-shell '[ -n $SSH_AUTH_SOCK ]' " \
  set-option -sg update-environment \"DISPLAY WINDOWID XAUTHORITY\"; \
  setenv -g SSH_AUTH_SOCK /tmp/ssh_auth_sock_tmux; \
  run-shell \"ln -sf $(find /tmp/ssh-* -type s -readable | head -n 1) /tmp/ssh_auth_sock_tmux\" \
"
```

**Caveat**

The above solution along with the other solutions are susceptible to a race condition when initiating multiple connections to the same machine.  Consider this:

- Client 1 Connect: SSH to machineX, start/attach tmux (writes `ssh_auth_sock` link)
- Client 2 Connect: SSH to machineX, start/attach tmux (overwrites `ssh_auth_sock` link)
- Client 2 Disconnect: Client 1 is left with a stale `ssh_auth_sock` link, thus breaking `ssh-agent`

However, this solution is slightly more resilient because it only overwrites the `ssh_auth_sock` link upon tmux start/attach, instead of upon initialization of a bash shell `~/.bash_profile` or ssh connection `~/.ssh/rc`

To cover this last race condition, one may add a key binding to reload the tmux configuration with a `(Ctrl-b r)` key sequence.

```sh
# ~/.tmux.conf

# reload config file
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

From within an active tmux session, executing this sequence when the `ssh_auth_sock` link goes stale will refresh the ssh-agent connection.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on @pymkin's answer above, add the following, which worked with tmux 3.2a on macOS 11.5.3:

1. To `~/.tmux.conf`:

```sh
# first, unset update-environment[SSH_AUTH_SOCK] (idx 3), to prevent
# the client overriding the global value
set-option -g -u update-environment[3]
# And set the global value to our static symlink'd path:
set-environment -g SSH_AUTH_SOCK $HOME/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
```

2. To `~/.ssh/rc`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# On SSH connection, create stable auth socket path for Tmux usage
if test "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"; then
    ln -sf "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
fi
```

What's going on? Tmux has the semi-helpful `update-environment` variable/feature to pick up certain environment variables *when a client connects*. I.e. when you do `tmux new` or `tmux attach`, it'll update the tmux environment from when you ran those commands. That's nice for new shells or commands you run inside tmux *afterwards*, but it doesn't help those shells you've started prior to the latest attach. To solve this, you could use some of the other answers here to have existing shells pick up this updated environment, but that's not the route I chose.

Instead, we're setting a *static* value for `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` inside tmux, which will be `~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock`. All shells inside tmux would pick that up, and never have to be updated later. Then, we configure ssh so that, upon connection, it updates that static path with a symlink to the latest real socket that ssh knows.

The missing piece from @pymkin's answer is that Tmux will have the *session* value override the *global* value, so doing `set-environment -g` isn't sufficient; it gets squashed whenever you re-attach. You also have to also tell tmux not to update `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in the session environment, so that the global value can make it through. That's what the `set-option -g -u` is about.

Comment: It's unfortunate that I have to unset `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in the `update-environment` variable by referring to it by its index as `update-environment[3]`, but there seems to be no way of referring to an array element by value. In any case, SSH_AUTH_SOCK is part of the default set of values in `update-environment` at index 3, so it's reasonably static.

Comment: See [Array options](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Advanced-Use#array-options) in the tmux wiki. Sadly, array options aren't explained in the tmux manpage

Comment: Thanks! It was a real pain to get this working until I found this anwser. Unfortunately, this breaks when SSHing to another host inside my tmux session. That can be fixed by linking to `~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock.$HOSTNAME` (and setting `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` accordingly), but `HOSTNAME` is not available in .tmux.conf. I realized it's simpler to set `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in my default shell's rc file (e.g. .`bashrc`) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a new fix to an old problem: I think it's simpler than the other fixes and there's no need to make a static socket or mess with the shell prompt or make a separate command you have to remember to run.

I added this code added to my .bashrc file:

```
if [[ -n $TMUX ]]; then
  _fix_ssh_agent_in_tmux () { if [[ ! -S $SSH_AUTH_SOCK ]]; then eval export $(tmux show-env | grep SSH_AUTH_SOCK); fi }
  ssh ()   { _fix_ssh_agent_in_tmux; command ssh $@; }
  scp ()   { _fix_ssh_agent_in_tmux; command scp $@; }
  git ()   { _fix_ssh_agent_in_tmux; command git $@; }
  rsync () { _fix_ssh_agent_in_tmux; command rsync $@; }
fi
```

If the shell is running within tmux, it redefines 'ssh' and its ilk to bash functions which test and fix SSH_AUTH_SOCK before actually running the real commands.

Note that `tmux show-env -g` also returns a value for SSH_AUTH_SOCK but that one is stale, I assume it's from whenever the tmux server started. The command above queries the current tmux session's environment which seems to be correct.

I'm using tmux 2.6 (ships with with Ubuntu 18.04) and it seems to work well.

Answer (score 1):

After coming across so many suggestions,  I finally figured out a solution that enables TMUX update the stale ssh agent after being attached. Basically, both the zshrc files on the local and remote machines need to be modified.

Insert the following codes into the local zshrc, which is based on [this reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132065/how-do-i-get-ssh-agent-to-work-in-all-terminals/132117#132117).

```sh
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/ssh-agent.$(hostname).sock
ssh-add -l 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
# The error of executing ssh-add command denotes a valid agent does not
# exist. 
if [ $? -ge 1 ]; then
  # remove the socket if it exists
  if [ -S "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" ]; then
    rm "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}"
  fi
  ssh-agent -a "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" >/dev/null
  # one week life time
  ssh-add -t 1W path-to-private-rsa-file
fi
```

Insert the following code into the remote zshrc, where the tmux session will be attached.

```sh
alias fixssh='eval $(tmux showenv -s SSH_AUTH_SOCK)'
```

Then ssh into the remote machine. The -A option is necessary.

```sh
ssh -A username@hostname
```

Attach the TMUX session. Check the TMUX evironment variables

```sh
# run this command in the shell
tmux showenv -s
# or run this command after prefix CTRL+A or CTRL+B
:show-environment
```

Run `fixssh` in the previously existed panes to update the ssh agent. If a new pane is created, it will automatically get the new ssh-agent.

Answer (score 1):

In case other fish shell users are wondering how to deal with this when using fish (as well as for my future self!). In my `fish_prompt` I added a call to the following function:

```
function _update_tmux_ssh
  if set -q TMUX
    eval (tmux show-environment SSH_AUTH_SOCK | sed 's/\=/ /' | sed 's/^/set /')
  end
end
```

I suppose that more advanced *nix users would know how to replace `sed` with something better, but this works (tmux 3.0, fish 3.1).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another simple Bash solution, using `PROMPT_COMMAND` to update the `SSH_*` vars inside `tmux` before each prompt is generated. The downside to this solution is that it doesn't take effect in existing shells until a new prompt is generated, because `PROMPT_COMMAND` is only run *before* creating new prompts.

Just add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
update_tmux_env () {
    # Only run for shells inside a tmux session.
    if [[ -n "$TMUX" ]]; then
        eval $(tmux show-env -s | grep '^SSH_')
    fi
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND=update_tmux_env
```

Comment: A better way to do this is to use `trap update_tmux_env DEBUG`, which means it gets executed before **executing  a command**, not before displaying the prompt. This solves the problem of needing to hit enter on a blank cmdline before the vars are updated.

Comment: AFAIK this is the only way to automatically update important ssh/X11/etc ssh connection related vars inside old shell sessions after doing `tmux attach`. The `trap` approach is nice because it also works even when you have multiple sessions sharing the same session group at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This is my small practical demo code. [github repo](https://github.com/CaptainVincent/Tmux-SSH-Agent-Forwarding)

My workaround still involves using a **symbolic link** to address the issue of SSH_AUTH_SOCK becoming invalid. However, I utilize a **double symbolic link** to differentiate between **sessions and clients**. The benefit is that this automated script can handle many edge cases. The downside is that this mechanism will retains few link files that have not invalid yet at the time of housekeeping check (you could check the timing in my tmux hook scripts). However, it is not a significant issue for me.